# Trying to find a Google Spreadsheet formula or query for this example

Tags: google-sheets

```
  A | B |  C  |  D  |  E   |  F  | G
name|num|quant|item|quant2
car | 5 | 100 |
    |   |     |wheel| 4
    |   |     |axel | 2
    |   |     |engine|1
truck| 2 | 20 |   
    |   |     |wheel| 6
    |   |     |bed  | 1
    |   |     | axel| 2
```

I need a formula which will do B*C*E.  the tables look like this, so it needs to be something like

=b$2*c$2*e3 and then dragged.... and then the next set, b$6*c$6*e7 and dragged, etc but i want sure how to get the cieling sort of something.  if b5 is empty, look at each above until it finds the one not filled.

I am trying to use this to get total quantity of parts per car, truck etc.... and then group by part.

I dont have a set of DB tables to do this, just a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add some additional information to resolve this.

I was thinking there would be a way to do a google script that would do this and update the file, but i couldnt seem to find it.

I first summed each group item:

```
=b$3*e4
```

and dragged for that grouping.

Then afterwards, i went to a selection of space and wrote up a query.

```
=query(D:F, "select D,sum(F) group by D")
```